# Django one to many query

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a one-to-many model relationship an trying to query both the main and the referenced model in views.
The **model.py** looks like this(simplified):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_number = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    ....


class Phase(models.Model):
    time_input_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    phase_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

**Views.py**:

How can I structure the views in order to pass all the fields to a template that shows info about the project and all its phases? I've tried so many things with no success, my brain just stopped functioning now.
**EDIT**
The current view is a mess: the info must be passed to various charts, this is one of them:

```
def ChartGaProgress(request, slug):
    labels = ['COMPLETED',
        'REMAINING']
    chartLabel = "GA DRAWINGS"
    chartdata = []
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug)
    phases = Phase.objects.filter(project=project)
    
    for phase in phases:
        a = {'id': phase.time_input_id, 'ga_drawings_completed':phase.ga_drawings_completed, 'ga_drawings_remaining':phase.ga_drawings_remaining}
        chartdata.append(a) 
    GaProgData = {
                     "labels":labels,
                     "chartLabel":chartLabel,
                     "chartdata":chartdata,
             }
    phases_qty = phases.count()
    project_obj = Project.objects.all()
    context = {'project_obj':project_obj}
    return render(request, {'project': project, 'phases': phases, 'phases_qty': phases_qty, "context": context})
```

Comment: How does the *current* view looks like?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just edited my question and added the view

Comment: ok, I've given up